# Twitter Bootstrap navigation working on desktop but not mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using the collapsing navigation menu from Twitter Bootstrap as demoed here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

It works fine when I test it in browsers on the desktop by resizing the browser window but nothing fires when I test it on my mobile (iPhone 4s).

The sample page above from Bootstrap works on my mobile so I've been comparing both and can't figure out what's causing it not to fire.

Anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: the link the collaspe menu is http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: Can you provide you code in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'll try get it on jsFiddle - big site. It's working fine on a colleague's Android handset. Still not firing on my iPhone and no error in the debug console.

Comment: If it works on an android you can try to clear your cache: From the Home screen, choose Settings > Safari. Tap Clear Cache.

Comment: @Steph did you ever figure this out - got identical problem it's destroying me!

Comment: Afraid I never did get to the bottom of it before handing over to another developer.

Comment: Updated collapse menu link: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Answer (score 4):

I remember facing the same issue. Anyway, this is what I did.

Put the following in head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is there another element which can be applied? The navbar fits the device, but all the content is about twice the width of the screen. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I updated bootstrap code to version 2.3.0 and mobile started working beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with tabbed navigation.

Worked fine on desktop but as soon as I went to iphone/ipad - dead.

It just made the #page-name appear in the URL.

But I missed a trick - I forgot to add this...

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Boom tabs now work on iphone/ipad